# shell script compare file with multiple line pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which is created after some manual configuration. 
I need to check this file automatically with a shell script.
The file looks like this:

```
eth0;eth0;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4c
eth1;eth1;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4d
eth2;eth2;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4e
eth3;eth3;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4f
eth4;eth4;48:df:37:58:da:44
eth5;eth5;48:df:37:58:da:45
eth6;eth6;48:df:37:58:da:46
eth7;eth7;48:df:37:58:da:47
```

I want to compare it to a pattern like this:

```
eth0;eth0;*
eth1;eth1;*
eth2;eth2;*
eth3;eth3;*
eth4;eth4;*
eth5;eth5;*
eth6;eth6;*
eth7;eth7;*
```

If I would only have to check this pattern I could run this loop:

```
c=0
while [ $c -le 7 ]
do
    if [ "$(grep "eth"${c}";eth"${c}";*" current_mapping)" ]; 
    then
        echo "eth$c ok" 

fi 
    (( c++ ))
done
```

There are 6 or more different patterns possible. A pattern could also look like this for example (depending and specific configuration requests):

```
eth4;eth0;*
eth5;eth1;*
eth6;eth2;*
eth7;eth3;*
eth0;eth4;*
eth1;eth5;*
eth2;eth6;*
eth3;eth7;*
```

So I don't think I can run a standard grep per line command in a loop. The eth numbers are not consistently the same.

Is it possible somehow to compare the whole file to pattern like it would be possible with grep for a single line?

Comment: It is not clear from your question. Do you want to grep something like `ethA;ethA` and drop others (for example, `ethX;ethY`)?

Comment: If it were just one line I would use this in a shell script: if  [ "$(grep "eth0;eth0*" /file/location)" ]; So basically I want to "grep" a multiple line pattern like the ones with the * because the MAC addresses are always different but the rest should be verified that it looks like in the pattern

Comment: Is first code block your input? What do you expect as an output?

Comment: first code block is content of a file and my input. As output I expect true or false after I check it if it looks like the pattern below.

Comment: I only want to check if the first part of every line (eth0;eth0;) is correct. So I put a * in the pattern, bcause MAC address is always different and doesn't need to be verified

Comment: Can you gives us expected output for the file(input)?

Comment: Please look at my updated answer and try the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file` is your data file and `patt` is your file that contains above pattern. You can use this `grep -f` in conjunction with `sed` in a process substitution that replaces `*` with `.*` and `?` with `.` to make it a workable regex.

```
grep -f <(sed 's/\*/.*/g; s/?/./g' patt) file
```

```
eth0;eth0;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4c
eth1;eth1;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4d
eth2;eth2;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4e
eth3;eth3;1c:98:ec:2a:1a:4f
eth4;eth4;48:df:37:58:da:44
eth5;eth5;48:df:37:58:da:45
eth6;eth6;48:df:37:58:da:46
eth7;eth7;48:df:37:58:da:47
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any:

```
grep -P '(eth[0-9]);\1'
grep -E '(eth[0-9]);\1'
sed -n '/\(eth[0-9]\);\1/p'
awk -F';' '$1 == $2'
```

There are commands only. Apply them to a pipe or file.

**Updated the answer after the question was edited.**

As we can see the task requirements are as follows:

- a file (a set of lines) formatted like `ethN;ethM;MAC`
- examine each line for equality `ethN` and `ethM`
- if they are equal, output a string `ethN ok`

If I understand the task correctly we can achieve this using the following code **without loops**:

```
awk -F';' '$1 == $2 { print $1, "ok" }'
```

Comment: I want to verify the whole content of the file to the pattern. I edited my question how this would work with grep in a loop if every line looks like the first pattern.
It is possible to have different configuration where it would look like the 2nd pattern. My loop wouldn't work with that.

Comment: Yes this would work if the file looks like the 1st code block. There are cases thou, where a line should look like eth4;eth0;MAC for example. If I want to to do this I would have to use my loop and array=("eth4;eth0;*" "eth5;eth1;*" "eth6;eth2;*" "eth7;eth3;*" "eth0;eth4;*" "eth1;eth5;*" "eth2;eth6;*" "eth3;eth7;*") (The loop from my answer, not my question)

Comment: It's all up to you. If you'd like to use loops, do it. Anyway, I've shown to you the working example for your task without loops.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this loop now and it does the job (current_mapping being the file with the content in the first code block of the question). I would have to create arrays with different patterns and use a case for every pattern. I was just wondering if there is something like grep for multiple lines, that could the same without writing this loop.

```
array=("eth0;eth0;*" "eth1;eth1;*" "eth2;eth2;*" "eth3;eth3;*" "eth4;eth4;*" "eth5;eth5;*" "eth6;eth6;*" "eth7;eth7;*")

c=1
while [ $c -le 8 ]
do

if [ ! "$(sed -n "${c}"p current_mapping | grep "${array[$c-1]}")" ]; 
then
echo "somethings wrong" 

fi 
(( c++ ))
done
```